# How to check the connection disconnect use PJNATH?

Tags: embedded-linux, pjsip

I use PJNATH to connect with webrtc datachannele. It can send and receive data now. But i don't known when the other peer disconnect. Although I can check connecton disconnect by heartbeat in application layer,but i think it not the best choice.  Is anyone who familiar with PJNATH can give me some suggest?

thanks~